# Parsing string and performing operation in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, split

I am trying to parse a traceroute string and get the server delays. I've managed to do that but the output includes the delay and "ms". How do i get rid of the "ms" and is it possible to do an average of the three delays?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = " 1  sgp-1.valve.net (103.28.54.1)  1.030 ms  1.040 ms  1.212 ms";
my ($a, $b, $delaya, $delayb, $delayc) = split /  /, $str;

print "$delaya\n";
print "$delayb\n";
print "$delayc\n";
```

Returns:

```
1.030 ms
1.040 ms
1.212 ms
```

Expected:

```
1.030
1.040
1.212
```

Comment: Is my approach right?

Comment: [Net::Traceroute](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Traceroute) might be useful.

Comment: Tip on `split`: a pattern `' '` (single space between quote marks) splits on any amount of any whitespace (and discards leading and trailing space; see docs).  Then if your line is certainly always in the same format you can do that and count positions: `my @delays = (split ' ', $str)[3,5,7];`.  The bad: relying on whitespace (or, number of fields). So perhaps regex is better here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a regexp instead of splitting:

```
my $str = " 1  sgp-1.valve.net (103.28.54.1)  1.030 ms  1.040 ms  1.212 ms";
my ($delaya, $delayb, $delayc) =
    ($str =~ /([0-9.]+)\s+ms\s+([0-9.]+)\s+ms\s+([0-9.]+)\s+ms/);
print join "\n", $delaya, $delayb, $delayc, "\n";
```

Yields:

```
1.030
1.040
1.212
```

Regexp breakdown (below expression is repeated 3 times):

```
(               # beginning of a capturing group
    [0-9.]+         # a sequence of numbers and dot (at least one character)
)               # end of a capturing group
\s+             # at least one space
ms              # string 'ms'
```

---

If you want the average then:

```
my $str = " 1  sgp-1.valve.net (103.28.54.1)  1.030 ms  1.040 ms  1.212 ms";
my @delays = ($str =~ /([0-9.]+)\s+ms\s+([0-9.]+)\s+ms\s+([0-9.]+)\s+ms/);
my $total;
$total += $_ for @delays;
my $avg = $total/@delays;
print $avg, "\n";
```

Yields:

```
1.094
```

Comment: Note: if there can be _another_ `N ms` (apart from these three), then listing all three in succession makes sure we don't pick that other one.  If not, can do `my @delays = $str =~ /([0-9.]+)\s+ms/g;`

Answer (score 2):

Probably the following code is what you are looking for (note: I print all 3 delays on same line for debug purpose).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $debug = 1;

while( <DATA> ) {
    my @delay = /(\S+) ms/g;
    printf "%.3f %.3f %.3f\n",@delay if $debug;
}

__DATA__
 1  sgp-1.valve.net (103.28.54.1)  1.030 ms  1.040 ms  1.212 ms
 2    abcd.some.net (104.62.71.8)  1.302 ms  1.510 ms  1.621 ms
```